# How to merge transparent cubes into one big chunk?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My world is made out of cubes like in Minecraft. However, when I tried to make my water blocks transparent, I got this ugly effect where I can see other sides of the cube:

http://prntscr.com/g680eb

How can I fix this so you don't see each cube, but like 1 big piece of water that is transparent like in Minecraft?

Comment: is it actually the other side of the same block? Or is it just the face of the next block?

Comment: I guess it is actually the face of the next block. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Distjubo it *IS* the face of the next block, since unity does backface culling by default

Comment: Either you have to remove those faces or use some kind of buffer to store where the water is visible and then draw with that buffer.

Comment: How can I remove faces? I am total beginner, so if you can help me out?

Comment: @FICHEKK minecraft does this for every type of block, not just water. this is done in order to reduce draw calls and maintain decent performance. when you figure out how to do this, you might want to do something similar for your other blocks

Comment: building / modifying meshes from code gets confusing *fast*, and wouldn't be something to explain in a single SO post. try starting here : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

Comment: I'm not a Unity dev, but a quick google search brought [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/438204/remove-parts-of-a-mesh.html) up. You should be able to use this as a starting point.

Comment: Maybe you don't even want a full cube mesh, but only the mesh of a single face for every voxel. That would make removing single faces a lot easier.

Comment: Then you could just loop through all blocks and check which faces are "exposed", and only draw those.

Comment: I prefer you create custom shader that cull front face. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html

Comment: @Tengku that wouldn't reduce draw calls, but then again, premature optimisation is bad, and i suppose it's a viable solution too.